# Do taxis accept non cash payment in Zurich

Tags: switzerland, taxis, zurich

Because of the short stay ( only one night and one day), I don't want to withdraw any CHF .

Do taxis accept non cash payment in Zurich ?

**Minor questions :**

- Are Uber and Lyft common in Zurich ?
- Is there any alternative
  transportations from Airport to "Stadion Letzigrund" ?

PS : All the expenses with receipt will be refunded .

Comment: One question at a time please!

Comment: @gerrit: Don't be silly. It's really all the same question, isn't it?

Comment: @TonyK , please calm the tone . They are part of  the same question. I was not going to create separate post for each question

Comment: @RaymondChenon: I don't understand your comment. I'm on your side here!

Comment: Got you are on my side. But please be respectful to @gerrit , even though he acted as a jerk :)

Comment: I did not mean to act disrespectful.  I apologise if I came across as such.  I consider that "do taxis accept payment X" and "is there Uber" are different questions.

Comment: @Raymond: "silly" is really not such a terrible word to use.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Do taxis accept non cash payment in Zurich?"

Yes, you can pay by Visa, Mastercard, Maestro, Amex and Diners. See [HERE](http://www.airport-taxi-zuerich.ch/de/zahlungsarten.html)

"Is there any alternative transportations from Airport to Stadion Letzigrund?"

Yes, take the S16 suburban train from the airport to Hardbrücke (7-8 minutes), from where it's a 1-km walk.

Comment: ok, so you have to book the taxi prior to the flight

Comment: Technically not, but many people do it, so if you arrive without a prior booking, you may not be able to get a seat